# CharSequence to int

Tags: java, android, int, charsequence

Is there a Way to converte a Charsequence or a String to an Ingeter?

```
CharSequence cs = "123";
int number = (int) cs;
```

I'm a Noob. Solution:

```
CharSequence cs = "123";
int number = Integer.parseInt(cs);
```

Comment: how about vice versa?

Comment: `CharSequence cs = String.valueOf(number);`

Comment: @passsy your comment should be the recommended option. Instead of unneccessary conversions.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use [`Integer.parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). If your `CharSequence` is not a `String`, then you need to convert it first using [`toString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#toString%28%29).

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(cs.toString());
```

Comment: In addition to the answer of Joachim, in your case the `CharSequence` cs is already a String. `CharSequence` is an `interface` implemented by String (but not only), so you didn't create an object of `CharSequence` (Since there is no such thing), but assigned a String to `cs`.

Answer (score 15):

Since Java 9 you can use [`Integer.parseInt(CharSequence s, int from, int to, int radix)`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.CharSequence-int-int-int-) to parse integers from any `CharSequence` without first converting it to a String:

```
CharSequence cs = new StringBuilder("4711");
int value = Integer.parseInt(cs, 0, cs.length(), 10);
```

Answer (score 5):

use this

```
int i=Integer.parseInt(cs.toString())
```

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt(cs.toString())`

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin

```
CharSeqString.toString.toInt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the parsers from the Wrapper classes (Integer, Float, etc)...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "1";
    int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

From Editview component,

```
TextView txtYear = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtYear);
int intYear = Integer.parseInt(txtYear.getText().toString());
```